# (Internal) Depth of Field Not Getting Right Spot

Tags: animation

So basically I've been using this format of creating focus for a while now:
[image]

[image]

I would make the focus object a plain axis, and well right now I have this shot with the plain axis so small and right at Godzilla's head, meant to cover only his head, but it covers everything around him and his whole body.
[image]

Is there a way I can actually get it to focus on a specific spot I want it to? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't use the defocus node. You can just select the camera, go to its settings, hit the high quality button and set the f-stop level down to like 0.4 to see very precise where you are focusing. Then, set a random focus distance in the box next to the f-stop setting. Go in the 3d view, hit 'N' and check the 'Depth of field' box under 'Shading'. Now you can see the focus distance in the viewport as it is going to be rendered. Now start playing with the distance in the camera settings. Also, you can set the F-stop back to your preference after you are sure of the distance.